# log shipping of biztalk database on SQL server 2008 standard edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, biztalk, log-shipping

I want to do log shipping for biztalk databases on SQL server 2008 standard edition (server A) to another SQL server 2008 standard edition (server B).

I was told that for biztalk, logshipping is not like standard logshipping.
I was able to find 2 links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296836%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296741%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx

but they are not talking about SQL 2008 servers.

Can anyone please help in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of biztalk?

Comment: It is Biztalk server 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biztalk does not support any form of sql server log shipping.  Biztalk uses marked transaction log backups to restore on a scheduled basis.  [For 2009 see What Is BizTalk Server Log Shipping?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308796(BTS.10).aspx)